# Two divs, 50% width each, floated left, get one over the other in IE7 on window resize

Tags: html, css

I have this simple code, two floated left divs inside a wrapper.

```
    <div id="wrap">

        <div class="right">
            <p>I am right</p>
        </div>

        <div class="left">
            <p>I am left</p>
        </div>

        <div style="clear: both"></div>

    </div><!-- wrap -->
```

Both divs are 50% width and here is the [demo](http://inutritie.ro/test/)

If I resize the browser window in IE7, the second div floats under the first.

How can this be fixed? I have been searching all over the net for a solution but with no luck.

Ty!

Comment: Looks like a rounding issue, not sure what needs to be done

Comment: If I make one div 49% it works:) - but there should be a fix. I have tried using :zoom1 on the wrapper to trigger hasLayout box behavior

Comment: Also I have tried giving the wrapper a min-height, also no luck

Comment: The only thing that worked was giving the wrapper a fixed width, like 980px, but that would be besides the point, since this will be the basis of a fluid design

Comment: You have `margin: 0 auto;` on `#wrap`.  I think you need to reset the CSS.

Comment: Here's a bit of information on resetting your CSS: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Comment: In the source code I have applied the Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 reset - just for the sake of the issue

Comment: What if you use `<!--[if IE 7]>` tag, and set width to 49.9%. That might work.

Comment: The real question should be why you're doing anything with consideration for a browser with a stable release of more than 4 years ago, and a total userbase of < 1%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 is buggy with sub-pixel rounding in this case.

You'll notice that if you change the browser width in IE7, half the time the layout works, and the other half the layout is broken due to the combined width of the `div`s being one pixel wider than it really should.

There are a few different things you can do to fix this, here's one:

http://jsbin.com/OfeCEHo/1/

```css
#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
    width: 50%;
    float:  left;
    background-color: red;
}
.right {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I also swapped the order of your left and right `div`s in the HTML.

Comment: This is interesting, does this work if you have lets say 8 divs floated left, each with 25% width? Meaning 4 divs on a row?

Comment: Yes, this technique works with that if each row is in its own container. The first three `div`s would have `width: 25%; float: left` and the last would have just `overflow: hidden`. Here's an [explanation](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).